# Get class and attribute names from AttributeError

Tags: python

How do I get the class and missing attribute from AttributeError, e.g.
when AttributeError says: `'NoneType' object has not attribute a`, I would like to get `"NoneType"` and `"a"`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the only thing you can retrieve from an `AttributeError` is the string with the error message:

```
try:
    str.s
except AttributeError as err:
    error_message, = err.args
    print("Error message:", error_message)
    raise
```

Comment: Also you can get type of variable which cause exception using `type(err.__cause__)` or `type(err.__context__)` *(in that case there's no difference)*.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the type information *out* of an AttributeError, you could probably use regex, since you know the format of the error message:

```
import re

try:
    None.attr
except AttributeError as e:
    matches = re.match(r"'([^']*)' object has no attribute '([^']*)'", str(e))
    obj_type = matches.group(1)
    attr_name = matches.group(2)
    print(f"Object type: {obj_type}, attribute name: {attr_name}")
# Object type: NoneType, attribute name: attr
```

Comment: That's **the only way**, you can't avoid string parsing. It's possible to get type of variable which caused exception, but to get attribute name you have to parse it either from error message or from line of code *(can be retrieved from traceback)*.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

try:
    # access attribute
except AttributeError as e:
    obj_type, attr_name = re.match(r"\'([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\' object has no attribute \'([a-zA-Z0-9\_]+)\'", str(e)).groups()
```

- First cast the error into text with `str(e)`
- Then, using regular expression pattern read the object type and the name of the attribute you're trying to access. The `groups()` method will return all the captured groups from the regex which are marked with parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! Can you help future readers by trying to explain how and why this works?